# How to replace company names at beginning, end or (as one word) in the middle of a string?

Tags: php, regex

Consider the following array:

```
$companies = array(
  'apple' => 'AAPL',
  'baxter' => 'BAX'
);
```

And the following strings:

```
apple at the beginning of string with bapple
here a string with apple in the middle
baxter baxter on first and second place mybaxters
and finally, baxter
```

I'm using the following loop to replace company names with their respective ticker:

```
foreach ($companies as $name => $ticker) {
  $tweet = str_replace(" $name", "<b>{COMPANY|$ticker}</b>", $tweet);
}
```

This results in

```
apple at the beginning of string with bapple
here a string with {COMPANY|AAPL} in the middle
baxter {COMPANY|BAX} on first and second place mybaxters
and finally, {COMPANY|BAX}
```

However, I would also like to cath company names at the beginning of a string:

```
{COMPANY|AAPL} at the beginning of string with bapple
here a string with {COMPANY|AAPL} in the middle
{COMPANY|BAX} {COMPANY|BAX} on first and second place mybaxters
and finally, {COMPANY|BAX}
```

But if I remove the space in `" $name"`, words like `bapple` will also be replaced:

```
{COMPANY|AAPL} at the beginning of string with b{COMPANY|AAPL}
```

In other words: I want to replace all instances of company names
 - when surrounded by spaces "an apple is lovely fruit"
 - when at the beginning of string with a space after "apple is wonderfull"
 - or when at the end of a string with leading space "so this is my apple"

This would probably require a regex, but I would need some help in writing it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace words with preg_replace without duplicates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480206/how-to-replace-words-with-preg-replace-without-duplicates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($companies as $name => $ticker) {
  $tweet = preg_replace('/\b'.preg_quote($name).'\b/', "<b>{COMPANY|$ticker}</b>", $tweet);
}
```

The regex uses so-called word boundaries: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

The output is now:

> **{COMPANY|AAPL}** at the beginning of string with bapple here a
>   string with **{COMPANY|AAPL}** in the middle **{COMPANY|BAX}**
>   **{COMPANY|BAX}** on first and second place mybaxters and finally,
>   **{COMPANY|BAX}**

If you also want to support things like `apples`, then take this code:

```
foreach ($companies as $name => $ticker) {
  $tweet = preg_replace('/\b'.preg_quote($name).'s{0,1}\b/', "<b>{COMPANY|$ticker}</b>", $tweet);
```

}

Comment: he doesnt want `bapple` to be replaced. `b{COMPANY|AAPL}` is wrong

Comment: Now you are correct. Even if this new answer was already posted, at least you provided some code :)

Comment: Thanks! What, finally, would be the regex if **a space after (not: before) the company name is allowed (but not mandatory)?** So `this is bapple and apples` would become `this is bapple and {COMPANY|AA}s`?

Comment: @Pr0no Do you mean the character `s` (in your example) or a space? Edited regex: http://codepad.org/2DNv0xab

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is regex with word boundaries `\b`

http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Answer (score 2):

I am not a php developer but you should use a regex: `"\b"+$name+"\b"`.

Answer (score 2):

The key things here are:

- Make sure you quote your company names before they go in to the regex, because you'll run in to problems if your company names contain characters that mean something in regex syntax
- Use word boundaries (`\b`) to identify strings that are "on their own"
- Wrap your company name in parenthesis in the regex, then you can access the parenthesis'd bit as  `$1` in the replacement if you need to

Consider the following example:

```
$companies = array(
  'apple'   => 'AAPL',
  'baxter'  => 'BAX'
);

$input = "apple at the beginning of string with bapple
here a string with apple in the middle
baxter baxter on first and second place mybaxters
and finally, baxter";


foreach($companies as $name => $code)
{
  $input = preg_replace(sprintf('/\b(%s)\b/i',preg_quote($name)),'{COMPANY:'.$code.'}',$input);
}

var_dump($input);
```

Which will give you:

```
{COMPANY:AAPL} at the beginning of string with bapple
here a string with {COMPANY:AAPL} in the middle
{COMPANY:BAX} {COMPANY:BAX} on first and second place mybaxters
and finally, {COMPANY:BAX}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply - one additional feature though: what would be the regex if **a space after (not: before) the company name is allowed (but not mandatory)?** So `this is bapple and apples` would become `this is bapple and {COMPANY|AA}s`?

Comment: Depends on what you expect to see afterwards. I doubt you'd see "Apples" in the context of Apple the company (maybe "Apple's"?). If so, you could try `"/\b(%s)('?s)?\b/"`

Comment: You are right that my suggestion doesn't make much sense, and your suggestion for apostroph-only cases is logical but in the strings I have to deal with, all punctuation has been removed (so apple's has become apples). No that I think about it: the regex should allow for "company name + s", and nothing else after. So `apple apples and bapple and applecider apple` would become `{COMPANY|AA} {COMPANY|AA}s and bapple and applecider {COMPANY|AA}`. Would that be possible? I'm not afraid for mistaken replacements, because the context of the strings is all tech indistry news :-)

Comment: My example in the previous comment does allow for that, the ? after the ' means that the apostrophe is optional

Answer (score 1):

Took me some time, but then you got something

```
$companies = array(
    'apple' => 'AAPL',
    'baxter' => 'BAX'
);

$str = 'apple at the beginning of string with bapple
here a string with apple in the middle
baxter baxter on first and second place mybaxters
and finally, baxter';

foreach($companies as $search => $company)
{
    $regex = '!(?<=\b|^)('.$search.')(?=\b|$)!ui';

    $str = preg_replace($regex, $company, $str);
}

echo $str;
```